# react firebase adding user as admin automatically changes the current account with the added account

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

***so im adding users to firestore as well as in authentication but doing this actually replaces the current user with that email which i dont want this as in the image after adding teacher the logged in account is replaced by added account i think its the useEffect which is doing this.[here is dashboard where the useEffect is showing the current account logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfJrg.png)***

> Add user.js

```
    const [data, setData] = useState({});
      const handleinput = e =>{
        const id = e.target.id;
        const value = e.target.value;
      
        setData({...data, [id]:value})
      }
      console.log(data)
    
      
      const handleadd = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
          const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            auth,
            data.email,
            data.password
          )
          setDoc(doc(db, "Teachers", res.user.uid), {
            ...data,
            timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
            
          });
        } catch (e){
          alert("Faculty added succesfully")
          console.log(e.message)
        }
      }
```

> authcontext

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signOut, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth'
import React, {
  createContext, 
  useContext, 
  useState, 
  useEffect} from 'react'
import { auth } from '../../firebase'

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

  const userIn = ( email, password) =>{
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  }

  //sign up context
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  const addusers = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) =>{
      console.log(currentUser);
      setUser(currentUser)
    })
    return () =>{
      unsubscribe()
    }
  },[])

  //logout
  const logout =() =>{
    return signOut(auth)
  }





  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{addusers, user, logout, userIn  }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const UserAuth =()=>{
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the JS SDK `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method the newly created user is automatically signed in when the method call is successful. You cannot prevent that.

The classical approach in your case is to use a Cloud Function to create the user, because Cloud Functions use the Admin SDK which allows creating users in the back-end without signing them in from the front-end.

You’ll find an example of this approach in the following article: [How to create an Admin module for managing Firebase users access and roles](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e).

Comment: do you have any simpler way i cant really get that

Comment: No, as explained in the answer, the JS SDK `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method the newly created user is automatically signed